# I am creating an API in Cake php 4, following the CMS Tutorial - Authentication. How to deal with the Error: Missing Route that I get when I post

Tags: api, authentication, cakephp-4.x

I am creating an API in Cake php 4, following the CMS Tutorial - Authentication, and I was getting an error when using Postman to post in Json, it was showing Error: Missing Route. I reviewed routing, controllers, etc. and could not find the cause. If anyone can help me out, I would appreciate it.

**Below is the code I created.**

Application.php

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App;

use Cake\Core\Configure;
use Cake\Core\ContainerInterface;
use Cake\Datasource\FactoryLocator;
use Cake\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware;
use Cake\Http\BaseApplication;
use Cake\Http\Middleware\BodyParserMiddleware;
use Cake\Http\Middleware\CsrfProtectionMiddleware;
use Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue;
use Cake\ORM\Locator\TableLocator;
use Cake\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware;
use Cake\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware;

use Authentication\AuthenticationService;
use Authentication\AuthenticationServiceInterface;
use Authentication\AuthenticationServiceProviderInterface;
use Authentication\Middleware\AuthenticationMiddleware;
use Cake\Routing\Router;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;

class Application extends BaseApplication implements AuthenticationServiceProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * Load all the application configuration and bootstrap logic.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function bootstrap(): void
    {
        // Call parent to load bootstrap from files.
        parent::bootstrap();

        if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') {
            $this->bootstrapCli();
        } else {
            FactoryLocator::add(
                'Table',
                (new TableLocator())->allowFallbackClass(false)
            );
        }

        /*
         * Only try to load DebugKit in development mode
         * Debug Kit should not be installed on a production system
         */
        if (Configure::read('debug')) {
            $this->addPlugin('DebugKit');
        }

        // Load more plugins here
    }

    /**
     * Setup the middleware queue your application will use.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue $middlewareQueue The middleware queue to setup.
     * @return \Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue The updated middleware queue.
     */
    public function middleware(MiddlewareQueue $middlewareQueue): MiddlewareQueue
    {
        $middlewareQueue

            ->add(new ErrorHandlerMiddleware(Configure::read('Error')))
            ->add(new AssetMiddleware([
                'cacheTime' => Configure::read('Asset.cacheTime'),
            ]))

            ->add(new RoutingMiddleware($this))
            ->add(new AuthenticationMiddleware($this))

            ->add(new BodyParserMiddleware());

        // Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Protection Middleware
        // https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/security/csrf.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-middleware
        // ->add(new CsrfProtectionMiddleware([
        //     'httponly' => true,
        // ]))


        // $csrf = new CsrfProtectionMiddleware();
        // $csrf->skipCheckCallback(function ($request) {
        //     if ($request->getParam('prefix') === 'Api') {
        //         return true;
        //     }
        // });

        //$middlewareQueue->add($csrf);

        return $middlewareQueue;
    }

    public function getAuthenticationService(ServerRequestInterface $request): AuthenticationServiceInterface
    {
        $authenticationService = new AuthenticationService([
            'unauthenticatedRedirect' => Router::url("login"),
            'queryParam' => 'redirect',
        ]);

        // identifiers を読み込み、email と password のフィールドを確認します
        $authenticationService->loadIdentifier('Authentication.Password', [
            'fields' => [
                'username' => 'email',
                'password' => 'password',
            ]
        ]);

        //  authenticatorsをロードしたら, 最初にセッションが必要です
        $authenticationService->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Session');
        // 入力した email と password をチェックする為のフォームデータを設定します
        $authenticationService->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Form', [
            'fields' => [
                'username' => 'email',
                'password' => 'password',
            ],
            //'loginUrl' => Router::url('/users/login'),
        ]);

        return $authenticationService;
    }

    /**
     * Register application container services.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Core\ContainerInterface $container The Container to update.
     * @return void
     * @link https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/dependency-injection.html#dependency-injection
     */
    public function services(ContainerInterface $container): void
    {
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrapping for CLI application.
     *
     * That is when running commands.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function bootstrapCli(): void
    {
        $this->addOptionalPlugin('Cake/Repl');
        $this->addOptionalPlugin('Bake');

        $this->addPlugin('Migrations');

        // Load more plugins here

    }
}
```

routers.php

```
<?php

use Cake\Routing\Route\DashedRoute;
use Cake\Routing\RouteBuilder;

return static function (RouteBuilder $routes) {

    $routes->setRouteClass(DashedRoute::class);

 
    $routes->prefix('Api', function (RouteBuilder $builder) {
        $builder->setExtensions(["json"]);

        $builder->post("/user/login", ["controller" => "PricePlus", "action" => "login"]);
        $builder->get("/add-category", ["controller" => "PricePlus", "action" => "addCategory"]);
    });
};
```

PricePlusController.php

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Controller\Api;

use App\Controller\AppController;

/**
 * PricePlus Controller
 *`your text`
 */
class PricePlusController extends AppController
{

    public function login()
    {
        $result = $this->Authentication->getResult();

        print_r($result);
        die;

        if ($result->isValid()) {
            $user = $result->getData();
        } else {
            $this->response = $this->response->withStatus(401);
            $user = [
                'message' => 'invalid user'
            ];
        }

        $this->set('user', $user);
        $this->viewBuilder()->setOption('serializa', 'user');
    }

    public function addCategory()
    {
        $this->set('user', "Hello");
        $this->viewBuilder()->setOption('serializa', 'user');
    }
}
```

I have looked into routing, controllers, etc. using the official documentation and website. The expected result is that I want to get user information.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKP9t.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6D6c.png)

Comment: What URL are you actually posting to with Postman?

Comment: The URL for postman is here.

http://localhost:9811/api/user/login.json

Also, I have added an image to the question above.
I hope you will find it helpful.

Comment: I haven't used routing prefixes, so I don't know if they're case sensitive. Have you tried "api" there instead of "Api"?

Comment: I have lowercased api. The result was Error: Missing Route as well. I have also added an image of the routing result, so I hope you can refer to it as well.